# How to get full screen on certain pages in my webapp

Tags: angular, html, typescript, fullscreen, html5-fullscreen

In my app i want to make some pages display on full screen.
Basically this is what i want:
"User cannot access the browser or computer desktop or take any other actions outside of window using the mouse".

I was trying to use this full screen API:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/screenfull

I am working in html5/angular 5. I made a directive like suggested in angular example on the API page. I used the selector "toggleFullscreen" with a button (taking to next page) on for example page 3. If i want full screen on page 4 and 5. Than putting the selector on page 3 next button taking me to page 4 should make the full screen on page 4. But it is not working. Page 4 is not displayed on full screen.

I am quite new to angular. So can anybody suggest some other way to achieve this functionality in my code? I can not figure out why this API don`t work for me.

Comment: Are you asking to lock the user into doing nothing but using your app?
That would be bad for so many reasons and not possible.

Comment: Yeah that`s what i want to do. I did not set the requirement. I was told to implement this functionality like this.

Comment: That would be so dangerous if they allowed it. Someone could have a webpage that locks a computer or device until you pay the ransom.

Answer (score 0):

```
toggleFullScreen() {
        let elem =  document.body; 
        let methodToBeInvoked = elem.requestFullscreen || 
         elem.webkitRequestFullScreen || elem['mozRequestFullscreen'] 
         || 
         elem['msRequestFullscreen']; 
        if(methodToBeInvoked) methodToBeInvoked.call(elem);

    }
```

call this function wherever you want to trigger full screen for example on submit button click invoke this method which will load the page on full screen

Comment: The function do not give any errors in my code. I want to call it on this button:                   <button class="ok" type="submit" [disabled]="inProgress['submit']" >{{ 'review.view.next' | translate }}</button>.                                                               
But it still it don`t get full screen on clicking the button.

Comment: can you create a stackbiltz example  so i can work on it